# Best way to implement SQL Many-to-Many joins

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have three tables, and their relevant columns are:

```
tPerson
-> PersonID

tPersonStatusHistory
-> PersonStatusHistoryID
-> PersonID
-> StatusID
-> PersonStatusDate

Status
-> StatusID
```

I want to store a full history of all the Statuses that a Person has ever had. But I also want easy access to the current status.

Query to get the current status:

```
SELECT TOP 1 StatusID FROM tPersonStatusHistory 
WHERE PersonID = ? ORDER BY PersonStatusDate DESC
```

What I want is a query that will fetch me a list of Person records, with their most recent StatusID as a column in the query.

We have tried the following approaches:

1. Including the above query as a sub-query in the select.
2. Adding a CurrentPersonStatusHistoryID column to the tPerson table and maintaining it using a computed column that calls a User-Defined-Function.
3. Maintaining the CurrentPersonStatusHistoryID column using a trigger on the tPersonStatusHistory table.

The query to pull up the Person records is quite high use, so I don't want to have to look up the History table each time. The trigger approach is closest to what I want, since the data is persisted in the Person table and is only changed when an update is made (which is by comparison not very often).

I find triggers difficult to maintain and I would prefer to stay away from them. I've also found that when doing an Insert-Select, or an Update query involving multiple records, the trigger is only called on the first record and not the others.

What I really want is to put some logic into the column definition of CurrentPersonStatusHistoryID, press Save and have it persisted and updated behind the scenes without my intervention.

Given that Many-to-Many relationships are common I was wondering if anyone else had come across a similar situation and had some insight into the highest performance, and preferably least hassle, way of implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use something like the following query, perhaps as a view. It will give you the most recent StatusID for each Person.

```
SELECT PersonID, StatusID
FROM (
    SELECT PersonID, StatusID,
        rank() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY PersonStatusDate DESC) as rnk
    FROM tPersonStatusHistory
) A
WHERE rnk = 1
```

I'm not sure that this satisfies your requirement for performance, but it's something you could look into.

Comment: I've never seen that one before, thank you; it certainly seems cleaner than the other methods. I'll turn this into a view and join to it instead of the table and see how I go.